# Return value from an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

How can I return the value from an async function?

I've the following Promise:

```js
function reqGitActivity (url) {
  const options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve(body)
    })
  })
}
```

Then I use this Promise with Async/Await

```js
async function githubActivity () {
    const gh = await reqGitActivity(`https://api.github.com/users/${github}/events`)
    return gh
}
```

And if I execute the function with:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(githubActivity()))
```

I only get the Promise but not the value returned from the request.

```
Promise {
     _c: [],
     _a: undefined,
     _s: 0,
     _d: false,
     _v: undefined,
     _h: 0,
     _n: false }
```

But if I put a console.log on the `gh` I got the value from the request, but I don't want `githubActivity()` to log the value I want to return the value.

I tried this too:

```js
async function githubActivity () {
    return await reqGitActivity(`https://api.github.com/users/${github}/events`)
    .then(function (res) {
      return res
    })
}
```

But I still only get the Promise and not the value from the resolve.

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried with var gh = ... instead of const gh = ... ?

Comment: @TudorConstantin Yeah, and still I got the Promise.

Comment: this is crazy - if you put a console.log(gh); before the return gh, the content is displayed

Comment: @Tudor Constantin Yeah. Me too, but on the return doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can only [access that value inside of a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337733/getting-value-from-returned-promise-from-async-function).

So, instead of `console.log(JSON.parse(githubActivity()))`, use:

```
githubActivity().then( body => console.log( JSON.parse( body ) ) )
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you! I was reading this too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise