# What is the correct syntax for a method declared as async?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-class

I stumbled upon the following ES6 method during a rewiew:

```
async getUsers(res) {
  User.findAll().then(users => res.json(users));
}
```

This seems buggy to me. I would have expected the following:

```
async getUsers(res) {
  return User.findAll().then(users => res.json(users));
}
```

But then, I know that async has many tricks such as auto-wrapping promises, so is my intuition correct?

Comment: `async` is not ES6, it is ES7

Comment: What is `res`? Btw, if there is no any `await` - you don't need `async` at all.

Comment: @zerkms Probably express response object

Comment: @zerkms indeed res is an express response object and User would be a sequelize model (returning promises)

Comment: @smnbbrv indeed async is ES7 but this is an ES6 method so my logic was that this would be an async "ES6 method"

Comment: So: 1. There should be `return` indeed 2. You don't need `async`

Comment: what I don't understand is why author is not confused about missing `await` call. `async` is just useless without it

Comment: @GurgHackpof you have a weird logic I must say...

Comment: @smnbbrv see this answer for async without await http://stackoverflow.com/a/35302535/1171013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as it is written (without the `return`) is likely fine as long as the caller does not need access to the asynchronously retrieved value.

First off, `async` is needed as part of your function definition ONLY if you plan on using `await` inside the function.  If you aren't using `await` inside (which your code does not show), then the `async` part of the definition is not needed.  So, it could probably be just this:

```
getUsers(res) {
  User.findAll().then(users => res.json(users));
}
```

Second, if a caller wants to use `await` on the `getUsers()` function, then it needs to return a promise (as you proposed).  If the caller will not use `await` with it or otherwise need any access to a return value, then the `return` is not necessary.  So, if you wanted to use `await` on this function, then it should probably be this:

```
getUsers(res) {
  // return promise so caller can get async value
  return User.findAll().then(users => {
      res.json(users);
      return users;      // return value so caller can get access to the value
  });
}
```

So, the original code may be just fine as long as the caller is never expecting an asynchronous return value from that function (which is possible here because the result of the async operation is being sent with `res.json()` and that may be the only result that is needed.  As far as await/async are concerned, you only have to return a promise from functions that you plan to use await on.

---

To recap:

1. `async` is only needed if you plan on using `await` inside the function.  Your function probably doesn't even need the `async` keyword on it at all.
2. A returned promise is only needed if the caller wants to be able to get access to the asynchronous response either via a traditional `f().then()` or via `let x = await f()`.
3. A caller can `await` a function that is not marked as `async`.  The `await` will get the return value from the function and, if the return value is not a promise it will wrap it in a resolved promise.  If it is a promise, it will wait for it to resolve.

FYI, this is a very good, short and sweet [review of async/await](http://rossboucher.com/await/#/) and how they interact with promises.

Comment: Very nice answer. So that is indeed why this code is full of races.