# Async function returning promise, instead of value

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, primitive

I'm trying to understand how async/await works in conjunction together with promises.

```
async function latestTime() {
  const bl = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  console.log(bl.timestamp); // Returns a primitive
  console.log(typeof bl.timestamp.then == 'function'); //Returns false - not a promise
  return bl.timestamp;
}
const time = latestTime(); // Promise { <pending> }
```

As far as I understand, await should be blocking and in the code above it seemingly blocks returning an object `bl` with the primitive `timestamp`. Then, my function returns the primitive value, however the time variable is set to a pending promise instead of that primitive. What am I missing?

Comment: that's what async functions do - read the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: `await should be blocking` no - blocking code in javascript is a "bad idea"™ and async/await has nothing to do with blocking at all

Comment: *Every* `async function` returns a promise so that inside of it you can `await` other promises, that's the whole point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An `async` function always returns a promise. That's how it reports the completion of its asynchronous work. If you're using it in another `async` function, you can use `await` to wait for its promise to settle, but in a non-`async` function (often at the top level or in an event handler), you have to use the promise directly, e.g.:

```js
latestTime()
.then(time => {
    console.log(time);
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

...though if you're doing this at the top level of a JavaScript module, all modern environments now support [top-level `await` in modules](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await):

```
const time = await latestTime();
```

(Note that if that promise is rejected, your module will fail to load. If your module can work meaningfully even if the promise fails, be sure to wrap that in `try`/`catch` to handle promise rejection.)

---

It **might** (or might not) throw some light on things to see, in explicit promise callback terms, how the JavaScript engine handles your `async` function under the covers:

```js
function latestTime() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
        .then(bl => {
            console.log(bl.timestamp);
            console.log(typeof bl.timestamp.then == 'function');
            resolve(bl.timestamp);
        })
        .catch(reject);
    });
}
```

Some important notes on that:

- The function you pass to `new Promise` (the *promise executor* function) gets called synchronously by `new Promise`.

  - Which is why the operation starts, `web3.eth.getBlock` is called synchronously to start the work.
- Any error (etc.) thrown within the promise executor gets caught by `new Promise` and converted into a promise rejection.
- Any error (etc.) thrown within a promise callback (like the one we're passing `then`) will get caught and converted into a rejection.

Answer (score 29):

Async prefix is a kind of wrapper for  Promises.

```
async function latestTime() {
    const bl = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
    console.log(bl.timestamp); // Returns a primitive
    console.log(typeof bl.timestamp.then == 'function'); //Returns false - not a promise
    return bl.timestamp;
}
```

Is the same as

```
function latestTime() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,success){
        const bl = web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
        bl.then(function(result){
            console.log(result.timestamp); // Returns a primitive
            console.log(typeof result.timestamp.then == 'function'); //Returns false - not a promise
            resolve(result.timestamp)
        })
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: There are a couple of issues with that translation of the `async` function. It's okay in very broad conceptual terms, but doesn't handle rejection correctly, has a syntax error, and gives a very surprising name (`success`?!) to the second argument passed to the promise executor (the function to use to **reject** the promise)...  :-)

Answer (score 12):

`async` function will return `Promise` anyway. Return value will be `Promise, so in your case it will be:

```
async function latestTime(): Promise<some primitive> {
  const bl = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  return bl.timestamp;
}
```

So, further you can use it function like:

```
const time = await latestTime();
```

But for achieving general view about `async/await` feature it will be better to read documentation.