# Why Promise???? Help me

Tags: node.js, vk

decided to start learning node js and at the same time writing a bot in VK. I wanted to make a function that displays the user's first and last name, but I get some kind of Promise. maybe this is a stupid question, but still.

```
const VkBot = require('node-vk-bot-api');

const bot = new VkBot('токен вк');

async function get_username (user_id) {
    var act = await bot.execute('users.get', {
        'user_ids': user_id,
    });

    return act;
    // return act.first_name + ' ' + act.last_name;
}

bot.event('message_new', (ctx) => {
    var text = ctx.message.text;
    var peer_id = ctx.message.peer_id;
    var user_id = ctx.message.from_id;
    // console.log(peer_id + ' | ' + get_username(user_id) + ' | ' + text);
    console.log(get_username(user_id))
});


bot.startPolling();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338277/async-function-returning-promise-instead-of-value)

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) | [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for `get_username`:

```
bot.event('message_new', async ctx => { // Callback async
    const text = ctx.message.text;
    const peer_id = ctx.message.peer_id;
    const user_id = ctx.message.from_id;
    console.log(await get_username(user_id)); // Wait for get_username
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your why.

> Promises are the ideal choice for handling asynchronous operations  in
> the simplest manner. They can handle multiple asynchronous operations
> easily  and provide better error handling than callbacks.

so in ES6 you can use async/await instead of callbacks, thats how you can achieve non blocking code.