# javascript: async function not returning fetched object from API but instead returns [object promise]

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to fetch data from an API and I tried following [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/) tutorial but it keeps returning *[Object Promise]* instead of the object with the course id. The fetch function works properly when I tested it in the console but it doesn't set the variable *'subject'* to the returned data. Is there any parts that need to be modified? Thank you

**localhost:1337/subjects/**

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": algebra",
"time": "TUES|2PM",
"instructor": "Alex Smith"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "biology",
"time": "WED|2PM",
"instructor": "Carl James"
}]
```

**script.js**

```
async function getSub(courseid)    {    
    async function getSubject(courseid) {
     var url = 'http://localhost:1337/subjects/'+courseid;
     let response = await fetch(url, {method: 'GET'});
     let data = await response.json();
     return data; 
 }

const subject = await getSubject(1); //returns [object Promise] not object with id=1 
}
```

**calling this function from another js file**

```
const info = await script.getSub(1);
```

Comment: Async functions _always_ return promises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338277/async-function-returning-promise-instead-of-value)

Comment: And you should use `response.json()` if you want an object.

Comment: I have updated the code with the modifications suggested however the error still persists

Comment: [It should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ojpcde4z/2/) the way you edited it.

Comment: Can you show the updated code. Because it is not possible that you get a Promise out of `await` and it is not possible to get something else out of an `async function`.

Comment: This is the same code I use, It's just encapsulated in another function since I call this function in other JS files but when I call it from other JS files it gives me object promise

Comment: Your outer function is just as async as the inner one is. Again, `async` functions _always_ return a Promise, never a value. Please read the accepted answer in the post linked in my first comment. You'll need to `await` `script.getSub(1)` as well. (Or use `.then()` on it.)

Comment: I updated the code above to better show what i was trying to do. I tried to use the settimeout but still no luck

Comment: @Ivar I'm getting another error when I placed await beside script.getSub(1) : 'Uncaught SyntaxError: await is a reserved identifier'

Comment: @starter-kid Then you likely put the `await` in the wrong spot, or the `script.getSub(1)` is not inside of an `async` function (although in that case I would expect a different error). Do you have it like `const info = await script.getSub(1);`?

Comment: yep like this const info = await script.getSub(1);

Answer (score -1):

You should use `await` when calling an `async` function:

```js
function getSubject(courseid) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:1337/subjects/'+courseid;
    return fetch(url, {method: 'GET'});
}

var subject = await getSubject(1);
console.log(subject)
```

Comment: I have tried this however same error still occurs

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try using that ?

Comment: Hi i've tried this as well but I still get object promise