# Chaining Async Await with loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have 2 functions with loops that I want to execute sequentially:

- Function A executes
- Within Function A there is a For loop triggering an external function
- Once loop in Function A is finished doing its thing, then we start with Function B

I have tried with the following code but function B starts in parallel, doesn't wait for Function A to finish:

```
async function sendPosts() {
    console.log("start send posts")
    for (let post of posts) {
        ...
  
        await channel.send({
            ...
        }).then((message) => {
            externalFunction(message);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    console.log("finish send posts")    
}

async function sendComments() {
    console.log("start send comments")
    for (let comment of commentsData) {
        ... 
    }
    console.log("finish send comments")
}   

sendPosts().then(sendComments());
```

Comment: `sendComments()` executes the function and assigns its return value as the resolve handler of `sendPosts()`. Just remove the `()`

Comment: ooh right. Yeah I get you now!

Comment: `sendPosts` don't return `Promise` - then why you chainging like `Promise` `sendPosts().then(sendComments());` or I am blind??

Comment: @Andreas want to put this as answer and ill mark it as correct?

Comment: Nope. I voted to close as typo (because I can never find the duplicate for this type of problem... :/).

Comment: @zbyso `async` functions always return a promise.

Comment: @zbyso [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51338277) | [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431) | [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884522)

Comment: `sendPosts().then(sendComments());` -> `sendPosts().then(() => sendComments());` or `sendPosts().then(sendComments);` see [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272) | [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16310423) | [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928)

Comment: @VLAZ @Noam thanks, I don't know this: "If you don't explicitly return a promise, the value you return will automatically be wrapped in a promise.", I do manually `return new Promise...` every time :)

Answer (score -1):

For of loop is not awaited. you looking for something as following

```
    for await (const variable of iterable)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Foreach loop has acting the same