# Fetch API return json object or response status

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm a bit stuck with the fetch API.
This is a simple Login function

```
export default class LoginService {
    async loginUser(u, p) {
        return fetch(API_URL + '/users/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': u, 'password': p })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
        }
}
```

When user is not found the in the backend return 400 bad request. How can I return the json object or the response status? Or maybe this practice is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Your server doesn't like the request you're sending.

Comment: *"When user is not found the in the backend return 400 bad request"* It really shouldn't do that. It should return [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).

Comment: Ok about the return status, but I'm not able to return the json object or the status code

Comment: @Old-fashioned-dev - On a successful response, your code is returning the result of parsing the JSON from the server. Are you saying you're not seeing that?

Comment: (Reading a bit between the lines, you *might* be having an issue with the fact that `loginUser` returns a promise. If so, these may help: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338277/async-function-returning-promise-instead-of-value), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call))

Answer (score 0):

> How can I return the json object or the response status?

The [`ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) response property gives you the high-level "worked/didn't work" for the HTTP call (`fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors — a footgun in the api you constantly see people falling afoul of).

I wouldn't *return* the response status, I'd include it in an error thrown by the `async` function. I typically do that like this:

```
async loginUser(u, p) {
    return fetch(API_URL + '/users/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': u, 'password': p })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`};
        }
        return response.json();
    }); // Note: No `catch` here!
}
```

But if you really want to *return* it:

```
async loginUser(u, p) {
    return fetch(API_URL + '/users/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'username': u, 'password': p })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return {failed: true, status: response.status};
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Turning rejections into fulfilments that way is generally not best practice, though.

Comment: Oh... Thank you very much! I didn't fully understand the use of return in fetch. Thank you!

Comment: @Old-fashioned-dev - Happy coding, felling traveler! :-)

Answer (score -3):

```
    .then(res=>{
    if(res.ok)
    {
       return response.json()
    }
    else{
    // return 400 bad request here
    }
    })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.