# Async/Await problem trying to create new instance with axios.create using auth0 token,

Tags: typescript, async-await, axios, auth0

Bearer token is not resolving in time:

Bearer [object Promise]
[image]

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Auth0Client } from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
import { auth0Config } from 'src/config';
import { paths } from 'src/paths';

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3001'

const auth0 = new Auth0Client({
  domain: auth0Config.issuer_base_url!,
  clientId: auth0Config.client_id!,
  cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
  authorizationParams: {
    audience: auth0Config.audience,
    redirect_uri: auth0Config.base_url + paths.auth.auth0.callback,
  },
});

async function getToken() {
  return await auth0.getTokenSilently()
}

const token = getToken()

export const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
});
```

I've tried wrapping instance in a function, but that didn't really work either because instance won't have methods available like .get, .push etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338277/async-function-returning-promise-instead-of-value)

Comment: Your `token` holds a `Promise` - you need to `await` it somewhere first or create `instance` in `.then` promise handler.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your getToken is an async function that should be called with await
so
const token = getToken()

should be

```
const token = await getToken()
```