# Using async function within synchronous code

Tags: node.js

I'm using a library called [sqs-consumer](https://github.com/bbc/sqs-consumer) to process SQS messages. The library is expecting the message handler to look like:

```
handleMessage: (message, done) => {
    // do some work with `message`
    done();
}
```

On the other hand though I have async code

```
async function sendEmail() {
    return await ...
}
```

Is there a good way to run the `sendEmail` within `handleMessage`, wait for it to finish, and then to call `done`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise)

Comment: Note that `return await` is pretty pointless if that's the only `await` you're using in the function - just use a standard function instead, and you can simply `return` the plain `Promise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your promise-based code inside a callback like this:

```
handleMessage: (message, done) => {
    // do some work with `message`
    sendEmail().then(done).catch(...);
}
```

In some cases, you could also make a new method for `handleMessage()` that actually expects a promise to be returned and works with that promise directly rather than using a plain callback at all.

---

Also, not that there is no point to using `return await ...` at the end of your function.  You can just return the promise directly:

So, instead of:

```
async function sendEmail() {
    // other code here
    return await someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}
```

You can just do:

```
async function sendEmail() {
    // other code here
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}
```

That extra `await` adds no value or utility.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the library doesn't care what you return from `handleMessage` you can also use async/await in the handlerMessage function directly:

```
handleMessage: async (message, done) => {
    await sendEmail();
    done();
}
```