# Is there an implicit return value to async functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

Are these two snippets the same?

The top version returns a promise in the arrow function, and the bottom one doesn't return anything. Is there an implicit return when using async, should I return null, do I need to return the const info?

When i look at how babel translates them it replaces async/await with generators that make it look like i should return the const info

```
// t.get() is a promise, set and delete are not

db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(infoRef).then(info => {
    t.set(db.doc(`/users/${uid}`), info.data());
    t.delete(infoRef);
  });
});

db.runTransaction(async t => {
  const info = await info.get(infoRef)
  t.set(db.doc(`/users/${uid}`), info.data());
  t.delete(infoRef);
});
```

[babel link](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=C4UwzsAUwAQLwD4YG8BQMYCcTAK6YDsZgA6Acx0gEoBuVAXytVVAkgEMwBPAgY2PhJ2Ad3YBLWKQpQqtZq2AAWDtz4DEKdDF4B7AhBgAbeDBHjJ5SnIzsCO4AAsQmSIbmMgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: I think `const info = await info.get(infoRef)` should be `const info = await t.get(infoRef)`

Comment: Yes, see this: [MDN: async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit return, but any returned value is wrapped in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

[Async functions implicitly return a promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431)

Returning a value from one promise passes that value as an argument to the next if the promise is [chained](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).

If you don't actually chain anything after the first promise, then the return value is ignored, and there is no point to including it.