# How to return promise in an async method?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I'm dealing with a code that makes calls to an async function. In this case, the `run` method performs an `await` call to a method that returns a string. How can I transform the `run` method to return, again, a promise?

I searched the Internet, but I cannot find a solution. I'm new to Typescript and asynchronous programming.

I'd also like to ask: Does the `await` keyword "transform" a returned promise in a string? The result is a string, but why do I not have to unwrap it with `.then()` to obtain the string? If the result was a promise, I could return it in the `run` method, but `run` must return a promise.

```
public async run(): Promise<IMyType> {
    log.info("Running item1 ...");

    let result: IMyType = {
        name: "name1",
        outcome: undefined,
        message: "",
        various: {}
    };

    result = await this.runCheck(result);
    if (result.outcome) {
        result.message = this.successMessage;
    } else {
        result.message = this.failMessage;
    }

    return result;
}


private async runCheck(
    result: IMyType
): Promise<IMyTypet>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/457268

Comment: async / await is syntactic sugar to help to work with promises in a seemingly synchronous way (meaning: the code looks like is synchronous, though it still is promise-based). An async function will *always* return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can return a promise in an async function:

```
let getSomeValue = async () : Promise<string> => {
    let promise: Promise<number> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve("my result") }, 50); //for example
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Then you can consume it like this:

```
let result = await getSomeValue();
```

and your question:

> "does the await keyword "transform" a returned promise in a string?"

Yes, "my result" will be assigned to result here.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer in your code.
When you mark a function with `async`, it means that it will return a promise, no matter what's inside the function. If you return a value, it will be the value that the promise has resolved with.

The `runCheck()` is marked with `async` and you are `await`-ing it to get the string value. The same goes for the `run()` function. You have marked it with `async` which means it will return a promise, no matter what's inside. You are returning the string value, which means you can just do this:

```
const theString = await object.run(); // theString is the value you return in function
```