# Result of await for Promise returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a simple function like this that I'm expecting `true` from.  It creates an `Observable` from `true`, turns it into a promise, and `await`s it:

```
    async function returnTrue() {
      return await of(true).toPromise();
    }

    var b = returnTrue();
    console.log("b is: ", b);
```

When the value of `b` is logged it logs:

`b is:Promise {}`

IIUC the other way to do this is to `pipe` the observable like this:

```
function returnFalse() {
  return of(false).pipe(map(b=>{
    return b;
    }));
}

const c = returnFalse();
console.log('Return value c: ', c);
```

In this case the value logged is:

```
Return value c:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…}}
```

Thoughts?

### Summary

Summarized the answers an thinking on this in order to do synchronous programming with RxJS Observables:

https://medium.com/p/6276721e674a

Comment: async functions return a Promise.

Comment: OK - That's simple enough :).  I guess looking at it it's kind of obvious, I just was not expecting it at first :)

Comment: may be a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any value returned from a context of an `async` function is wrapped in a Promise.

In your code although you return the result of `await` which actually waits for the `of(true).toPromise()` Promise to get resolved, which it does but the resolved value is wrapped again in a promise because of the `async` function context.

This is stated in the `async` function [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in MDN:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which
>   returns an AsyncFunction object. An asynchronous function is a
>   function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an
>   implicit Promise to return its result

In the second code using `Observable`, you are using the `pipe` operator which by definition returns another `Observable` after applying the given operations (map in your case) from the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pipe):

```
pipe(operations: ...*): Observable
```

> Return: Observable     the Observable result of all of the operators
>   having been called in the order they were passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var b = await returnTrue()
```

PS. forget about var - read about const & let

Comment: Stackblitz draws errors.  Don't think we can use `await` outside of an async context.

Comment: @Ole you can't sadly, but there is a proposal for a top level `await` [source](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

Comment: Voted this up - I think it's good to know what we can't do.  Plus Dawid needs some points.