# Example of an 'Async' Function Being Defined Without Corresponding 'Await' Syntax

Tags: javascript, async-await

When using `async/await` syntax we write it like so:

```
async function getAllRecords() {
   let records = await getDataFromServer();
   // Do something with records
}
```

In other words, if you want to `await` within a function, you need to make sure you use the `async` keyword as well (as that changes how this code is handled behind the scenes). All good so far.

My question is: are there cases where you define a function using the `async` keyword, without also using `await` within the body of the function?

For instance, I came across this:

```
async sybaseUpdateCustomer(exId, customer, cardType, lastFour, expireMonth, expireYear, billingStreet, billingZip, defaultPaymentMethod) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(`Updating customer for customer ${customerId} in sybase.`);
      sybase.query(
        "INSERT INTO cc_customers (ex_id, identifier, card_type, last_four, expiration_month, expiration_year, address, zip, isDefault) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        [exId, customerId, cardType, lastFour, expireMonth, expireYear, billingStreet, billingZip, defaultPaymentMethod],
        (res) => {
          if (res.status == 'failure') return reject(res.data);
          return resolve(true);
        }
      );
    });
}
```

Notice the `async` keyword is being used, but there is no `await` anywhere in the body of the function. Is this correct syntax? And, if so, what is `async` doing here, and is it necessary for the function to execute correctly?

Comment: The `async` keyword means the function will always return a `Promise` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/4636715). So, regarding your sample function body returns a Promise, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: if you notice, what is happening in the 2nd example is that the function returns a Promise, which it itself an async object. So yes it makes sense not to await here. What is returned to the caller is another asynchronous context.

Comment: @ADyson, I did notice that, yes, but then I think to myself, if you're explicitly setting up the promise within the function, anyway, why use the "async" keyword at all? For the sake of code readability, maybe? It does allow other developers to quickly notice this is going to involve a promise, but one could also argue it's functionally redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `async` function returns a `Promise`, and it's fine to use the value returned by an `async` function directly as a `Promise` without using the `await` keyword.

The `async` might or might not be necessary on the function being called, depending on how it's written. `async` is definitely required if the function has any `await`s inside of it, and it's also necessary if the function returns a value, say a number, which is meant to be treated as `Promise<number>`.

Comment: So, to clarify, in my specific example above, while `async` is fine, is it also necessary?

Comment: The function will work just the same without the `async`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

`async` means two things: one, it's necessary to `await` things in the function's body, and two, the return value will be wrapped in a promise. Even if there's no return statement, the result will be `undefined` wrapped with a promise. Here:

```js
const foo = async () => {};
foo().then(console.log);
```

So I guess `async` without any `await` is another way of doing `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: To me it seems redundant in the example I included above, because `async` sets things up for a promise, but then in the code above the promise is then explicitly set up in the function body, anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is kind of redundant.