# How to return data from await/async loops?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have several async http requests I need to make to an API to fetch some data. It's pretty simple to setup in a loop in a function like this:

```
async function fetchData() {

  let data = {}
  for (const asset of someAssets) {
    try {
      data[asset.id] = await library.fetchSomeData(asset.id)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  return data
}

let data = fetchData()
console.log(data)
```

The problem here is that the last `console.log(data)` comes back as a pending Promise instead of the data. How do I fix this issue? Do I need to wrap my "main" code (at the bottom) in a `async` function as well? At what point does my entire project just need to wrapped around a `async` function?

Comment: You still need to `await` the `fetchData` function. Or use a `then`.

Comment: @VLAZ please find a better duplicate. That is a canonical question about callback-based asynchronicity, not `async` / `await` or even promises. While the answers do contain information about promises, that is a disingenuous "duplicate" for this question.

Comment: @JakeWilson does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/1541563) answer your question?