# If I define an async function and use await in the body, do I need to use await when calling the function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

an example:

```
async doSomething() {
  await asyncCall();
}
```

Do I need to use `await` when I call my `doSomething` function?

```
await doSomething();
```

or is this fine?

```
doSomething();
```

Comment: Do you want to wait for `doSomething()` to finish or not? Do you want to handle any errors it might throw?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I do want to wait for `doSomething()` to finish

Comment: then you need `await`. if you want to run it *in the background* and not wait you dont use `await`.

Comment: Then...you have to `await` it. That's what `await` does.

Comment: [An `async function` *always* returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/1048572), regardless whether you use `await` in the body or not, and yes you will need to `await` (or `return`) that promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand that async/await is really just "sugar" on top of Promises. In other words, `doSomething` *still* returns a `Promise` (you can't use async await to get away from this fact!). So, to answer your question, you still need to use `await` (or chain a `then` call) to handle the eventual resolved or rejected Promise value.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `doSomething()` returns a Promise. For you to return the data from an *async* function, you need to resolve or reject the promise.

When you do:

```
await doSomething();
```

`doSomething()` will wait for `asyncCall()` to be resolved.

When you do:

```
doSomething();
```

`doSomething()` will resolve `asyncCall()`in the background.

I think your confusion comes from the fact that await is only valid in async functions in javascript. If you want to run `await doSomething()` outside a async function, just wrap it around an anonymous async function like:

```
(async() => {
  await doSomething()
})();
```