# async function with MySQL SELECT request returns [object Promise] but writes correct answer in console

Tags: node.js, mysql2, vk

I started to create a bot for working with the MySQL database together with the vk-io module, but I came across an error that I did not understand
The function below tries to pull one single value from the database, which is definitely there. This value is even displayed in the console but not in the code.

```
async function getlastweek(){
    connection.query('SELECT weekstartdate FROM schedule ORDER BY weekstartdate DESC LIMIT 1', async function(err, results) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(String(results[0].weekstartdate).slice(0, 10))
    return String(results[0].weekstartdate).slice(0, 10)
})
}
```

So far, this function is only used in this place in the code.

```
bot.hear(/^Добавить новую неделю$/, async (msg)=>{
    if(msg.messagePayload){
        if(msg.messagePayload.command === 'add week'){
            
            vk.api.messages.send({
                peer_id: msg.peerId,
                random_id: (Math.random() * (9999999 - 1) + 1),
                message: 'Последняя неделя была ' + getlastweek() + '\nСегодня ' + now
            })
            
        }else{msg.send('Команду вызывать надо через админку')}
    }else{msg.send('Нее, эт так работать не будет')}
})
```

It returns absolutely normal text in the console:

```
Mon Aug 16
```

but returns

```
[object Promise]
```

into code

I tried to find answer in the internet but found nothing for examples.

Comment: All async functions always return promises. If you want the value, resolve it with await or .then. The internet is absolutely not short of examples of promise usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise)

Comment: It is not the answer at all, i tried .then but it still sends [object Promise]

Comment: @tantalum Unfortunately no,  getlastweek().then(res => lastweek=res) from your link still returns [object Promise]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the function being async. Node provides you multi threading which means that it does not wait for the previous line to complete.
So this is why your code returns object promise

Comment: After deleting async it became undefined

Comment: Did you remove the keyword await as well?

Comment: from this bot command and from function, yes

Comment: you have to make some changes if you change your function from async to sync. Async function doesn't have blocks while sync function does have blocks. 

for example:

//Sync function
var result = database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable");
console.log("Query finished");
console.log("Next line");



// Example 2 - Asynchronous (doesn't block) 

database.query("SELECT * FROM hugetable", function(result) {
    console.log("Query finished");
});
console.log("Next line");

Comment: even if i put `message: 'Последняя неделя была ' + connection.query(SELECT weekstartdate FROM schedule ORDER BY weekstartdate DESC LIMIT 1).weekstartdate + \nСегодня  + now` it still will show me undefined. '...[0].weekstartdate' will show only error in console `Cannot read property weekstartdate of undefined`