# Why does this aysnc function not implicitly return a promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I read in this Stack Overflow question [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise) that:

> "An Async function will always return a promise. If you don't
> explicitly return a promise, the value you return will automatically
> be wrapped in a promise."

So why does my `getData2()` function below return `undefined`?

```js
const getData = async() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('this is the data');
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const getData2 = async() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return 'this is the data without an explicit promise';
  }, 1000);
};

(async() => {
  console.log(await getData2()); // DOES NOT WORK: displays 'undefined' immediately
  console.log(await getData()); // WORKS: waits one second and displays data
})();
```

Comment: You've got a function without a `return` statement. It *does* return a Promise, but the value is `undefined` because the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: Look at what function your `return` statement is inside of.  In `getData2()`, the `return is returning from the `setTimeout()` callback function, NOT from your `getData2()` function.  There is no `return` statement in your actual `getData2()` function so it returns `undefined` which means the promise that `getData2()` returns, resolves with `undefined`.

Comment: It does return a promise but the promise gets resolved immediately since you don't await anything inside the function. And since you don't return anything from the function (all it does is call `setTimeout()`) it resolves with `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getData2` *is* returning a Promise, but you're `await`ing it, which extracts the resolve value from the Promise.

```
console.log(await getData2());
```

turns into

```
console.log(await promiseThatResolvesToUndefined);
```

```
console.log(undefined);
```

If you don't `await` it, you'll see the Promise.

```js
const getData2 = async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return 'this is the data without an explicit promise';
    }, 1000);
};

(async () => {
    console.log(getData2());
})();
```

The resolve value is `undefined` because nothing is being returned inside the body of `getData2`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `async` but with using return inside an inner function (in this case a lambda), which returns from that inner function (*not* the outer function), and `setTimeout` then ignores that return value. The correct way to do this is `getData` (but without the `async` keyword which adds an second layer of `Promise`).