# I need to loop over an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So I'm building a web scraper, and I need (want) to loop over my axios request.

most of the code is here... the rest is data and functions to return pieces.

When I run this, it's not waiting for anything, it just flies over it.  Where am I going wrong?

I dont' know if you need this info, but the page checker seems to think you do, so....

I'm trying to scrape google for LinkedIn pages that contain a plainly visible email address.   The code at this point is unfinished, but the gist is this.  I've got some proxies.  If I get a captcha page, I change proxies.  If I get search results, I parse them for the data I want.  If there is a next link, I go to the next page.  If everything is right, I should be zipping through google in no time.

```
while( (task == "new") || (task == "next") || (task=="proxy"))
{
    switch(task) {
        case "new":
            url = getNextUrl(1);
            if(url == "end") {
                console.log("Search completed!");
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "next":
            url = getNextUrl(pageNumber)
            break;
        case "proxy":
        break;
    }

    proxy = getNextProxy();

        
    (async () => {
        
        let proxy = getNextProxy().toString().split(":");
        console.log(proxy);

        console.log(url);
        await axios.get(url,{
            headers: {
                'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.66 Safari/537.36"
            },
            proxy: false,
            httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent.HttpsProxyAgent(`http://${proxy[0]}:${proxy[1]}`)
            },
            {timeout:5000})
            .then((response) =>{
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

                let captcha = $("#captcha-form");
                if(captcha.length > 0)
                {
                    task = "proxy";
                    return;
                }
                

                let searchitems = $(".jtfYYd");
                for(let i=0; i < searchitems.length; i++)
                {
                    let element = searchitems[i];
                    let c = $(element).attr("class");

                    let link = $(element).find(".yuRUbf").find("a").attr('href');
                    let title = $(element).find("h3").text();
                    let details = $(element).find(".MUxGbd.wuQ4Ob.WZ8Tjf").find("span");
                    let stub = $(element).find(".VwiC3b.yXK7lf.MUxGbd.yDYNvb.lyLwlc.lEBKkf").find("span").text();

                    console.log();
                    console.log("Title:     " + title);
                    console.log("Link:      " + link);
                    console.log("Details:   " + details);
                    console.log("Stub:      " + stub);
                }

                let botstuff = $("#botstuff");
                console.log("botstuff: " + botstuff.text());

                if(botstuff.text().indexOf("Next") > 1)
                {
                    task = "next";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(searchitems.length == 0) {
                        task = "proxy";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        task="new"
                    }
                }
                //botstuff: Page Navigation123Next
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                task = "proxy";
                //console.log(error);
            });
    })();
}
```

Comment: You seem to know about `async`/`await`, why are you not using it?

Comment: I don't know about anything, man.  I'm just hobbling this together.  What am I missing?

Comment: Put the `async` IIFE around the loop, put the `await` inside the loop body.

Comment: Thank you sir. (or ma'am, whatever applies.)

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop executes synchronously.

The async IIFE function synchronously returns a promise for results obtained (typically asynchronously at a later time) within the function body. Hence

while( conditional-expresion) {

```
   (async()=>{ .. do stuff .. }()

};
```

synchronously evaluates the IIFE which value is a promise object. The promise object is not used in the code. Looping continues without waiting for any changes to be made to the variables being tested, resulting most likely in an infinite loop.

The solution for this question would involve removing the async IIFE from around the `await axios(...)` statement and placing the `while` loop in an asynchronous function to allow the use of the `await` operator. This would also allow coding the `then/catch` promise chain using `await` operators if you wish.

For those unfamiliar with asynchronous JavaScript it's worth noting that JS does not have a sleep function and you can't obtain asynchronous results inline from synchronous code. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise) for more information.