# Why sometime I do get "Promise { <pending> }" response?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have a class like below:

```
class User implements IUser{
  static async findByEmail(email: IUser["email"]) {
    const users = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email]);
    if (!users.length || !users[0]) {
      return null;
    }
    return users[0];
  };

  static async count() {
    const count = await Pools.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM users;');
    try {
      if (!count.length || !count[0]) {
        return null;
      }
      console.log('this is from inside the count method', count[0]);
      return count;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

And calling the class methods like the following:

```
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const existingUser = await Users.findByEmail(req.body.email);
      if (!existingUser) {
        throw new BadRequestError("Invalid credentials");
      }
      console.log(existingUser);
      const count = Users.count();
      console.log(count);
      }
   }
```

I get this results:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'admin@u.com',
    password: '12345',
    username: 'admin@u.com',
    admin: 1,
    created_at: 2023-01-06T02:31:14.000Z
  }
]
Promise { <pending> }
this is from inside the count method [ { count: 4 } ]
```

I have defined and used both functions in a similar way, but one of them works as expected but the other one returns `Promise { <pending> }` instead of `[ { count: 4 } ]` that the other console log returns from inside the `count()` function.

Why 2 similar methods work differently? How should I get the desired result(`[ { count: 4 } ]`) from the second one?

Comment: `const count = await Users.count();`

Comment: @Konrad: Oh! You right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `await` in this line:

```
console.log(existingUser);
const count = Users.count();  // here is missing the await
console.log(count);
```

change to this:

```
const count = await Users.count();
```

Comment: I will accept this in 10 mins.

Comment: @best_of_man don't you mean you promise to accept it in 10 min?

Answer (score 1):

Because `count()` is a async function. Async will mostly returns every value with a promise unless you awaits. You can see more discussion in this question. [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise)