# Async await unexpectedly stops execution

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have two async functions in a module. Currently they are both just meant to wait, since the actual logic isn't implemented yet.

#### Async module

```
export async function foo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('foo');
    }, 500);
  });
}

export async function bar() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('bar');
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

In the main code, I am calling these two functions sequentially in another function. I want `foo` to finishe before `bar` starts, so I'm using `await`.

#### Main code

```
import { foo, bar } from './myModule'

async function submit() {
  await foo();
  await bar();

  // do other stuff
  otherStuff();
}

submit();
```

This code logs 'foo' but then stops working. It doesn't call `bar` nor `otherStuff`. What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668474/6608142), async functions always return a Promise. I tried removing the Promise from `foo` and `bar`, since both are declared as async, but then all functions are called without waiting for the previous one to finish, i.e. `await` doesn't have any effect at all.

Comment: You never resolve the promise.

Comment: Protip: never do `new Promise` inside an `async function` _unless you absolutely know what you're doing_.

Comment: @DallogFheir I thought the `await` is for resolving the promise returned by an `async` function.

Comment: When there are callbacks in your code, you do have to create promises like you did. For example with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Dai That's not a problem here (but yes, the `function`s don't need to be `async`)

Comment: @KorbenDose `await` waits until the promise is resolved or rejected. You have to resolve (or reject) it inside the callback, otherwise it will just hang forever.

Comment: There’s almost never a good reason to use the `async` keyword on a function which doesn’t use the `await` keyword internally.

Comment: @Quentin I was thinking about that, too. If I leave away the `async`, it works the same way. In the actual implementation though, I will need it.

Comment: Totally agree! However, some linters force you to add the `async` keyword by convention, just because it returns a promise. It's just that the returned promise is created by hand, not with sugar syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are callbacks in your code - because of a library or the user of `setTimeout()` for example - you may be forced to create promises by hand.

In this case, what you did is correct, but you forgot to **resolve** those promises! Said differently: you promised something, but you didn't keep your word.

Here is the working code:

```
export async function foo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('foo');
       resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

export async function bar() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('bar');
       resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

> Additionally, according to this answer, async functions always return a `Promise`. I tried removing the `Promise` from foo and bar, since both are declared as async, but then all functions are called without waiting for the previous one to finish, i.e. await doesn't have any effect at all.

When the answer says "async functions always return a `Promise`", it's because declaring a function as `async` will create a wrapper for you:

```
async function foo() {
  return 1;
}
```

is a sugar syntax for:

```
function foo(): Promise<number> {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}
```

which works the same as:

```
function foo(): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
  })
}
```

But since you are currently using `setTimeout()`, which uses a callback, this is not a promise. Something needs to be called back. So simply adding the sugar syntax `async` will not do what you intend.

For example, imagine you attempt to do this:

```js
async function foo() {
  setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('foo');
  }, 500);
}
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
function foo(): Promise<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>> {
  return Promise.resolve(
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('foo');
    }, 500);
  )
}
```

Which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how come it doesn't work anymore, as soon as I remove the Promise? I thought `async` functions automatically return a Promise?

Answer (score -1):

In JS, when you create a `new Promise` using the Promise constructor, you need to call the `resolve` function because it's an integral part of how promises work. The resolve function is used to fulfill a promise, indicating that a certain asynchronous operation has completed successfully, and the promise should transition from a pending state to a fulfilled state. This is essential for handling asynchronous operations.

So in this case, this code works:

```
async function foo() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('foo')
            resolve('foo')
        }, 200);
    });
}

async function bar() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('bar')
            resolve('bar')
        }, 200);
    });
}

async function submit() {
    await foo()
    await bar()
}

submit()
```

Comment: This code works, but you don't have to resolve a string. It's not OP's intent to do that.

Comment: You are right! But if you want passing data (e.g. JSON) it´s necessary.