# wait for a promise of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Im trying to download a bucket from S3

```
async function downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix) {
  return s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: buckt, Prefix: prefix },
    (err, obj) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        var promises = []

        obj.Contents.forEach(element => {
            if (element.Size > 0) {
                var p = downloadFileFromS3({ Bucket: buckt, Key: element.Key });
                promises.push(p)
            }
        });
        return promises
    });
  }
}

async function downloadFileFromS3(item) {

    var file = s3.getObject(item,
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    file.createReadStream()
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(item));

    return file.promise()
}
```

In order to wait for all the downloads to happen I want to do something like:

> Promise.all(downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix))

But it is not working, I am not sure about how to do a wait of a promise returning a list of promises

Comment: The `files` here is a list of all files returned from all the async calls: `const files = await Promise.all(downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix))` The bottleneck here is the file that takes the longest to download, since they are all downloaded simultaneously.

Comment: Do not pass a callback if you want to use promises?!

Comment: How can I do it without a callback? Im new in nodeJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`s3.listObjectsV2()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) method returns an [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html), which provides a [`.promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) method, which turns the Node callback style into a then-able Promise:

```js
async function downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix) {
  try {
    var obj = await s3.listObjectsV2({
      Bucket: buckt,
      Prefix: prefix
    }).promise(); // Convert into a Promise, which can be await-ed
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  return Promise.all(
    obj.Contents
      .filter((element) => element.size > 0)
      .map((element) => downloadFileFromS3({
        Bucket: buckt,
        Key: element.Key
      }))
    );
  }
}

// Usage:
await downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix);
```

Note that if you were to return the Array of Promises directly, you would have to use it like:

```js
await Promise.all(await downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix)); // Extra await, to get rid of the extra Promise
```

Comment: And if I need  to download several buckets at the same time, How would I do it?
Could you expand the answer adding this case as well?
Thank you!

Comment: Something like `await Promise.all([downloadBucketRaw(bucktA, prefixA), downloadBucketRaw(bucktB, prefixB)])`

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you're not properly handling promises in the downloadBucketRaw function. The s3.listObjectsV2 method does not return a promise, so you can't directly use async/await with it.

To fix this, you can wrap the callback-based function with a Promise and resolve it once the callback is called. Here's an updated version of your code:

You can rewrite your code like below

```
function downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: buckt, Prefix: prefix }, (err, obj) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    var promises = [];

    obj.Contents.forEach(element => {
      if (element.Size > 0) {
        var p = downloadFileFromS3({ Bucket: buckt, Key: element.Key });
        promises.push(p);
      }
    });

    resolve(promises);
  }
});});}


   async function downloadFileFromS3(item) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
s3.getObject(item, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    var file = data.Body;

    file.createReadStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(item));

    resolve(file.promise());
  }
});});}

downloadBucketRaw(buckt, prefix).then(promises => Promise.all(promises)).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Note that `async` functions technically do not have to return a `Promise` as long as you `await` inside the function appropriately. See: [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-await-implicitly-returns-promise)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, but Nitish is using the `new Promise` for promisfication of the callback API. It should however *only* promisify the s3 calls, not put the rest of the code in the callback as well - and using `new Promise` is actually unnecessary as AWS provides a native promise API, see ghybs' answer