# Fetch api doesn't return data but a Promise

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, fetch

I am calling fakestoreapi with fetch by creating an async function. I am returning await response.json(); but at the end I am getting a Promise. Even if I try to declare a variable outside this function and assign **data = await response.json();** it is **undefined**. But when I **console.log(data)** then it logs the actuall data to console. My code is:

```
//let products = [];

const getProducts = async () => {
 const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
 const data = await response.json();
 console.log(data);// this works and logs data to console
 //products = data; this is undefined when logged to console.
 return data; // this gives back a promise.
}

console.log(getProducts());
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async function implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302431/async-function-implicitly-returns-promise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> Each time when an async function is called, it returns a new Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception uncaught within the async function.

So, the async function always return a promise.

You need to resolve it first:

```
//let products = [];

const getProducts = async () => {
   const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
   const data = await response.json();
   console.log(data);// this works and logs data to console
   //products = data; this is undefined when logged to console.
   return data; // this gives back a promise.
}

getProducts().then(products => {
    console.log(products);
});
```

Comment: Please "[_avoid trying to answer questions which..._ _...have already been asked and answered many times before_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)".

Comment: If we uncomment the line **//let products = [];** and assign products to function call after than where we are logging products and it still produces undefined.

Comment: @JAkhtar Yes, it expected behaviour. You will receive updated products only inside "then" clause, because it executes after the async action is performed.